# Multi-Tenancy Drools Spring Web-Application with Stateful KieSession On Startup vs Runtime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, drools

I am trying to implement a multi-tenancy drools web-application on Spring. I am finding that the JPA persisted KieSession that I create for each tenant is triggering the rule. But for a CEP example (System Reboot), I can see facts are added and it fires but it does not complete the full rule (the `then` part) after receiving 3 events, it is like the loaded stateful KieSession does not hold state.

I followed this example on [github](https://github.com/samimaftabahmed/spring-drools-persistence/tree/master) and was able to repurpose it to execute the same CEP rule just fine, the KieSession held state and updated the User object, so I know its not a rule issue.

The difference between that and the multi-tenancy version is that in the example from github the KieSession is created as a [bean](https://github.com/samimaftabahmed/spring-drools-persistence/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sam/springdroolspersistence/config/DynamicDroolsConfig.java#L67) on start up being created/loaded from the database (MySQL).

I can't figure out what is the difference between creating the KieSession as bean vs creating a KieSession first storing it in the db and then using the KieSession loaded from the db when executing the rule at runtime.

Below is my attempt at creating and reusing a KieSession from a db.

---

Application

```
package com.example.springdroolsexample;

import com.example.springdroolsexample.model.SystemRebootEvent;
import com.example.springdroolsexample.model.User;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.kie.api.KieBase;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieBuilder;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieFileSystem;
import org.kie.api.builder.model.KieBaseModel;
import org.kie.api.builder.model.KieModuleModel;
import org.kie.api.conf.EqualityBehaviorOption;
import org.kie.api.conf.EventProcessingOption;
import org.kie.api.persistence.jpa.KieStoreServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.Environment;
import org.kie.api.runtime.EnvironmentName;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

@EntityScan(basePackages = {"org.drools.persistence.info"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class SpringDroolsExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDroolsExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    private final Map<String, Long> tenantIdSessionIdMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Long, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();

    @GetMapping("{tenantId}/session")
    public Map<String, Long> initSessionForTenant(@PathVariable String tenantId) {

        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

        KieModuleModel kieModuleModel = kieServices.newKieModuleModel();

        KieBaseModel kieBaseModel1 = kieModuleModel.newKieBaseModel(tenantId)
                .setDefault( true )
                .setEqualsBehavior( EqualityBehaviorOption.EQUALITY )
                .setEventProcessingMode( EventProcessingOption.STREAM );

        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        kieFileSystem.writeKModuleXML(kieModuleModel.toXML());

        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/example/springdroolsexample/model/reboot.drl"));
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();

        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

        KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase(tenantId);
        KieSession kieSession = kieServices.getStoreServices().newKieSession(kieBase, null, getEnvironment());
        Long sessionId = kieSession.getIdentifier();
        log.info("Creating New Session with SessionID {} -> kieContainer{} -> kieBase{}", sessionId, kieContainer, kieBase);

        tenantIdSessionIdMap.putIfAbsent(tenantId, sessionId);
        return tenantIdSessionIdMap;
    }

    @PostMapping("{tenantId}/systemReboot")
    public User executeRuleForTenant(
            @PathVariable
            String tenantId,
            @RequestBody
            final SystemRebootEvent systemRebootEvent
    ) {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

        Long sessionId = tenantIdSessionIdMap.get(tenantId);

        KieStoreServices storeServices = kieServices.getStoreServices();

        KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase(tenantId);
        KieSession kieSession = storeServices.loadKieSession(sessionId, kieBase, null, getEnvironment());

        kieSession.insert(systemRebootEvent);
        User user = userMap.getOrDefault(systemRebootEvent.getUserId(),new User(systemRebootEvent.getUserId(), "barry") );
        userMap.putIfAbsent(systemRebootEvent.getUserId(), user);

        kieSession.insert(user);

        kieSession.fireAllRules();
        return user;
    }

    private Environment getEnvironment() {
        Environment env = KieServices.Factory.get().newEnvironment();
        env.set(EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, entityManagerFactory);
        env.set(EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER, platformTransactionManager);
        return env;
    }
}
```

POJOs

```
package com.example.springdroolsexample.model;

import java.util.Date;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.kie.api.definition.type.Duration;
import org.kie.api.definition.type.Role;
import org.kie.api.definition.type.Timestamp;

@Role(Role.Type.EVENT)
@Timestamp("ts")
@Duration("duration")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SystemRebootEvent {
    private Date ts;
    private Long duration;
    private Long computerId;
    private Long userId;

    public SystemRebootEvent(Date ts, Long duration, Long computerId, Long userId) {
        this.ts = ts;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.computerId = computerId;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}

---------------------------------------------

package com.example.springdroolsexample.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private boolean notified;
    
    public User(Long id, String username) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.drools.persistence=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=debug
```

The rule used `reboot.drl`

```
package com.example.springdroolsexample.model;

rule "Computer is rebooting too many times"
when
    $r1 : SystemRebootEvent($cId : computerId, $uId: userId)
    $numberOfTimes : Number(this >= 2) from accumulate(
        $r2 : SystemRebootEvent(this != $r1,
                                computerId == $cId,
                                this meets[1h] $r1),
                                count($r2)
                                )
    $u : User(id == $uId, notified == false)
then
    System.out.println($u.getUsername() + ", your computer was rebooted " + $numberOfTimes + " times after a reboot" );
    modify($u) {
        setNotified(true);
    }
end
```

For the mysql database I used a docker

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  my-db:
```

using Postman to send the SystemRebootEvent

```
{
    "ts": "{{todayDate}}",
    "duration": 10000,
    "computerId": 1,
    "userId": 111
}
```

`todayDate` is a pre-request script

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("todayDate", new Date().toISOString());
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>8.41.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.41.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-xml-support</artifactId>
            <version>8.41.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
            <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Is this really the smallest reproducible example?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have updated the code to replace DAOs to maps and move code into one class. I believe this is the smallest I can make it

Comment: I found that using CEP rules did not work, in the end I was able to reproduce this example https://github.com/mariofusco/drools-quarkus-reliable using spring and mysql db